# Environment Variables not present in Windows Powershell, but everywhere else is fine

Tags: environment-variables, environment

Thank you for taking the time to check out this posting. A while ago I accidentally deleted my PATHs record from my env variables. I have been trying to correct pick the right paths and fixing this but I have been struggling. Windows Command Line and Git Bash can correctly find the path to packages and modules I am trying to utilize but Windows Power Shell cannot... what am I doing wrong?

Here is the error in powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\jorda> git
git : The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ git
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\jorda> $env:PATH
C:\Python\3.11.4\x64;C:\Python\3.11.4\x64\Scripts;C:\Users\jorda\actions-runner\_work;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey;C:\Python\3.11.4\x64;C:\Python\3.11.4\x64\Scripts;C:\Users\jorda\actions-runner\_work;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;
```

Here is it in command line:

```
C:\Users\jorda>PATH
PATH=C:\Python\3.11.4\x64;C:\Python\3.11.4\x64\Scripts;C:\Users\jorda\actions-runner\_work;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey;C:\Python\3.11.4\x64;C:\Python\3.11.4\x64\Scripts;C:\Users\jorda\actions-runner\_work;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;

C:\Users\jorda>git
usage: git [-v | --version] [-h | --help] [-C <path>] [-c <name>=<value>]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p | --paginate | -P | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           [--config-env=<name>=<envvar>] <command> [<args>]
```

and it works perfectly fine...

Comment: Show, don't tell, please -- provide transcripts.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I added a picture, does this help?

Comment: Thank you for that. (In the future, post text _as text_ rather than screenshots as given in [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122), but it's enough to be a starting point).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy except when I run it in command line or bash it runs just fine, I have git stored in Program Files\Git\bin. Clearly it's not running

Comment: If you fully qualify the path, does it work? (I expect it will, but this is about ruling things out).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, all paths should fully qualify, starting with C:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254603/discussion-between-jordan-k-and-charles-duffy).

Comment: (1) try specifying `git.exe` instead (2) check if you have env var PATHEXT set correctly; CMD.EXE apparently resolves programs without it but PowerShell doesn't.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, my PATHEXT only had .CPL, even after adding the other locations still no update. My powershell seems to have nothing, no pip, python, any type of command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my own answer...
I must have also deleted PATHEXT.

Didn't realize I needed all of these!
.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC